# stripe connect charge once and divide to multiple connected seller accounts

Tags: android, ios, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, stripe-connect

let say following is an order: 
Item A - $10 - Seller A
Item A1 - $15 - Seller A
Item B - $20 - Seller B

Subtotal - $45
Postage Fee - $16.98
Order Total - $61.98

Now I have implemented stripe connect and it works fine with only one seller. I have used Collecting platform fees (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges).
But how do I split up charge and send correspond amount to multiple seller connected account?

Help appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

If you and your sellers are based in the US, you can use the [separate charges & transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers.) method.

Otherwise, you can use [destination charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) like you mentioned, but you'd need to create one charge per seller.

In any case, I recommend you write to support at https://support.stripe.com/email and explain your business model with as much detail as possible, so that we can advise you on which payment flow you should use.